# What is the best way to detect outliers

Tags: r, regression, outliers

I have a dataset of financial data. I want to see if there are any outliers in the dataset, so I make a regression: Stockprice = price_book + price_earnings + price_sales + sector

I think a randomForest model is sutable for the task - but i am a bit uncertain how to use a model to find outliers. Is there any problems in using the same dataset for prediction and estimation? And in this case, does it make sense to divide the dataset in a training and testing set?

Comment: Begin by characterizing what you would consider an "outlier" to be: it depends on your objectives, the quality of the data, and what you will do with any outliers you find.

Comment: I majorly second whuber’s comment about needing to define what an “outlier” means to you.

Comment: Outlier is where the predicted value is far away from the observed...

Comment: I’m missing something, because if that is the case, then you just define what “far” is and look and the predictions that missed by that much, something like predictions[abs(y-predictions)>=7] in R.

Comment: True.. but how do i estimate my predictions? that is the question..... (right now i just take the residual from the estimated model (for each observation)).. is that "doable"?